# android application stopped working suddenly after adding facebook sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a new android project in eclipse

I tried running that and it ran giving the usual hello world output

Now for adding a Facebook login I downloaded [facebook sdk 3.17 version](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-3.17.0.zip)

I imported the facebookSDK project.

Now i tried running my app and it is stopping suddenly !

[image]

Also i am not able to import Facebook sdk versions above 3.17

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement this in your manifest?

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
```